# What is the relation between Beilinson's conjectures and Standard conjectures of algebraic cycles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, motives, algebraic-cycles

Do Standard conjectures on the K-theory of varieties over finite field have implications in the motivic cohomology of Z where exist the correct formalism of Beilinson's conjectures?

What is the motivic relation between them?

Comment: "Standard conjectures on algebraic cycles" mean usually something else ...